# C# AutoComplete Function

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I want to make an Auto Complete Function for Example: If i type AWP it shows all AWP Commands and if i douple click on one it inserts the command to the richtextbox and another function converts the command to an ID

Only Problem is that if i Type Skin.AWP and then AWP it does not show the AutoCompletion Commands like it should, same if i press enter and type AWP

My Code:

```
    public List<string> autoCompleteSkinsList = new List<string>();

    public ConfigMaker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_ASIIMOV");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_BOOM");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Dragon Lore");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Forest DDPAT");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Pink DDPAT");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Snake Camo");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Lightning Strike");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Safari Mesh");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Corticera");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Redline");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Man-o'-war");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Electric Hive");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Pit Viper");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Worm God");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Medusa");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Sun in Leo");
        autoCompleteSkinsList.Add("AWP_Hyper Beast");

    }

    public void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_ASIIMOV", "279");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_BOOM", "174");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Dragon Lore", "344");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Forest DDPAT", "5");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Pink DDPAT", "84");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Snake Camo", "30");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Lightning Strike", "51");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Safari Mesh", "72");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Corticera", "181");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Redline", "259");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Man-o'-war", "395");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Electric Hive", "227");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Pit Viper", "251");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Worm God", "424");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Medusa", "446");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Sun in Leo", "451");
        TextBox.Rtf = TextBox.Rtf.Replace("AWP_Hyper Beast", "475");

        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        if (TextBox.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (String SkinList in autoCompleteSkinsList)
        {
            if (SkinList.Contains(TextBox.Text))
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(SkinList);
            }

        }
    }

    public void listBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox.Text = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    }
```

Example Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA1gS.jpg

Comment: so you want the listbox to be populated with something depending on what is being typed in to the text box?
Such as:
User types AWP and listbox gets filled with AWP related items?

Comment: exactly, and if the user then double clicks the item inside the listbox it inserts the item into the textbox

Comment: Well the short answer is that you're looking for the string from the text box in the list...so if you type "Skin.AWP" it will not find it in the list. Same thing if you press enter. Everything in the list starts with "AWP" and doesn't contain anything with "SKIN.AWP". you should rewrite the code to find "AWP" in the text and then display the options in the list box accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, I would do something like this instead:

```
        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        if (TextBox.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (TextBox.Text.Contains("AWP"))
        {
            listBox2.DataSource = autoCompleteSkinsList;
            listBox2.Refresh();
        }            
    }
    public void listBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox.Text = listBox2.Items[listBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    }
```